# Как создать для каждого обьекта в базе свою привязку /username на django?

Tags: python, html, django

Подскажите как создавать каждому обьекту свою url привязку например 127.0.0.1:800/Rassul.
Пытался вот так, но создает только одну страницу :
Файл urls.py в приложений:

```
for i in account.objects.all():
if i.account_login == i.account_login:
    userlogin = i.account_login
    print(userlogin)
    urlpatterns = [
        path('', views.main, name = 'main'),
        path('forgot', views.forgot, name = 'forgot'),
        path('addaccount', views.addaccount, name = 'addaccount'),
        path(userlogin, views.profile, name = userlogin)
    ]
```

Файл views.py:

```
def profile(request):
for a in account.objects.all():
    return render(request, 'frontend/' + a.account_login + '.html')
```

Comment: А зачем вы делаете для каждого юзера отдельный `html` файл?

Comment: А у вас для каждого пользователя есть отдельная `HTML` страница? И зачем в `profile` вы используете `for` если же возвращаете `render` первого елемента?

Comment: Это я просто тестировал

Comment: Даже если 1 html файл привизать все равно только 1 страничка будет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Models:

```
class AdvUser(AbstractUser): # Студенты
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=30 ,db_index=True, verbose_name="Отчество", blank=True)
    img_user = models.ImageField('Аватар', upload_to='images/user/', blank=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=30 , verbose_name="Номер телефона", blank=True)
```

views

```
@user_passes_test_custom(check_group_and_activation, login_url='/manager-school/login')
def get_teachers(request):
    teachers = AdvUser.objects.filter(groups__name='Teacher')
    return render(request, "manager/other/teachers_list.html", {"teachers": teachers})


@user_passes_test_custom(check_group_and_activation, login_url='/manager-school/login')
def get_teacher_card(request, teacher_id):
    teacher = get_object_or_404(AdvUser, id=teacher_id)
    return render(request, "manager/other/teacher_card.html", {"teacher": teacher})
```

url

```
path('teachers/', get_teachers, name='get_teachers'),
path('teacher/<int:teacher_id>', get_teacher_card, name='get_teacher_card'),
```

Мой Advuser  содержит в себе всех пользователей которые есть. Это и студенты и преподаватели.
Я так понимаю вы хотите сделать что бы на одной странице был один объект и на другой странице был другой объект. Если это разные модели то следовательно нужно писать разные views. И в ней передавать путь к html шаблону в котором будет отображаться тот или иной объект. Надеюсь я вам помог!